# Transformar string em array excluindo os valores repetidos

Tags: php, array

Em PHP fiz um script que pega cada palavra de uma tring e transforma elas em uma array, dando explode nos espaços vazios. Depois ele elimina as palavras repetidas e mostra cada uma delas, assim:

```
<?php
$hashtag = "#caio #azul #caio #azul #leão #orelha #caio  #caio  #caio";
//
$hashtagArray = explode(" ", $hashtag);
// exclui elementos vazios
$hashtagArray = array_filter($hashtagArray);
// exclui elementos iguais
$hashtagArray = array_unique($hashtagArray);
// reseta as chaves
$hashtagArray = array_values($hashtagArray);
// cria uma array
$hashtagArrayDuplica = array();
foreach ($hashtagArray as &$value) {
    // repito a checagem, para evitar erros
    if (!in_array($value, $hashtagArrayDuplica)) {
        $hashtagArrayDuplica[] = $value;
        echo $value."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

O resultado obtido é esse:

```
#caio
#azul
#leão
#orelha
```

O que aparenta estar certo. Mas incrivelmente no servidor do cliente, essa aplicação continua mostrando os itens repetidos, praticamente desconsidera o meu código, não sei se é pela versão do PHP, ou qualquer outro motivo (não posso ver o script rodando lá, só recebo print screen)... o que pode ser? Será que pode existir algum caractere especial? Será que existe outra forma de fazer essa verificação, para ver se no servidor dele funciona?

PS: reparem que no meu código eu tento verificar 2 vezes se tem algo repetido, foi uma tentativa de não dar erro no cliente, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Pede pro cliente manda um print do `phpinfo()`

Comment: Somente `explode`, `array_filter` e  `array_unique` que tem na pergunta fazem o que pretende. [Veja aqui](https://ideone.com/A0rz8w). O problema certamente não é da versão pois essas 3 funções são suportadas a partir do PHP4(pode confirmar na documentação de cada uma). Suspeito que o problema seja outro.

Comment: Verifiquei e lá está rodando a versão 5.6

Comment: Talvez alguma forma de limpar cada palavra, tirando qualquer caractere diferente?

Comment: O problema não deve estar nesse código e sim noutra coisa. Sugiro começar por ativar os warnings todos para tentar ver quaisquer outros problemas que possam existir. E pode ir testando cada função individualmente numa página nova de teste passo a passo até perceber onde está o problema.

Comment: Você pode testar seu código em diferentes versões do PHP nesse link http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/04bd3a78eabf54735755d284c766c8a54fdc1318

Comment: Nada errado http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eb9ef3f04f2f82b00776d14263cfac68a1883759

Comment: em outro site https://ideone.com/AnF7Ik

Comment: Valeu @LeoCaracciolo não conhecia esses sites, muito útil!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poderia testar dessa forma aqui ?

```
$hashtag = "#caio #azul #caio #azul #leão #orelha #caio  #caio  #caio";
//
$hashtagArray = explode(" ", $hashtag);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($hashtagArray);
echo "</pre>";

foreach ($hashtagArray as $key => $value){
  if (strlen($value)>0){
    $new[trim($value)] = $value;
  }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($new);
echo "</pre>";

exit();
```

Uma outra pergunta ... esse código já deu erro antes? Pode ser que eles não estejam colocando seu arquivo no lugar certo no servidor, aí tu nunca conseguiria saber o que está de errado, porque estaria executando 1 código antigo...

Comment: Eles estão pondo no lugar certo sim, pois outras funções nesse mesmo arquivo funcionam bem. Fiz agora uma versão com o seu código, e enviei, vamos ver! Valeu.